# Variable containing the number of rows affected by previous DELETE? (in a function)

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a function that is used as an INSERT trigger. This function deletes rows that would conflict with [the serial number in] the row being inserted. It works beautifully, so I'd really rather not debate the merits of the concept.

```
DECLARE
re1 feeds_item.shareurl%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT regexp_replace(NEW.shareurl, '/[^/]+(-[0-9]+\.html)$','/[^/]+\\1') INTO re1;
RAISE NOTICE 'DELETEing rows from feeds_item where shareurl ~ ''%''', re1;

DELETE FROM feeds_item where shareurl ~ re1;
RETURN NEW;
END;
```

I would like to add to the NOTICE an indication of how many rows are affected (aka: deleted). How can I do that (using LANGUAGE 'plpgsql')?

**UPDATE:**
Base on some excellent guidance from "Chicken in the kitchen", I have changed it to this:

```
DECLARE
re1 feeds_item.shareurl%TYPE;
num_rows int;
BEGIN
SELECT regexp_replace(NEW.shareurl, '/[^/]+(-[0-9]+\.html)$','/[^/]+\\1') INTO re1;

DELETE FROM feeds_item where shareurl ~ re1;
IF FOUND THEN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS num_rows = ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE NOTICE 'DELETEd % row(s) from feeds_item where shareurl ~ ''%''', num_rows, re1;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Oracle PL/SQL, the system variable to store the number of deleted / inserted / updated rows is:

```
SQL%ROWCOUNT
```

After a DELETE / INSERT / UPDATE statement, and BEFORE COMMITTING, you can store SQL%ROWCOUNT in a variable of type NUMBER.  Remember that COMMIT or ROLLBACK reset to ZERO the value of SQL%ROWCOUNT, so you have to copy the SQL%ROWCOUNT value in a variable BEFORE COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

Example:

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE
      affected_rows   NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
   BEGIN
      DELETE FROM feeds_item
            WHERE shareurl = re1;

      affected_rows := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.
       put_line (
            'This DELETE would affect '
         || affected_rows
         || ' records in FEEDS_ITEM table.');
      ROLLBACK;
   END;
END;
```

I have found also this interesting SOLUTION (source: http://markmail.org/message/grqap2pncqd6w3sp )

> On 4/7/07, Karthikeyan Sundaram  wrote:
>
> Hi,
>
> ```
> I am using 8.1.0 postgres and trying to write a plpgsql block.  In that I am inserting a row.  I want to check to see if the row has been
> ```
>
> inserted or not.
>
> In oracle we can say like this
>
> ```
> begin
>   insert into table_a values (1);
>   if sql%rowcount > 0
>   then
>     dbms.output.put_line('rows inserted');
>   else
>     dbms.output.put_line('rows not inserted');
>  end if;  end;
> ```
>
> Is there something equal to sql%rowcount in postgres?   Please help.
>
> Regards  skarthi
>
> Maybe:
>
> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW
>
> Click on the link above, you'll see this content:
>
> 37.6.6. Obtaining the Result Status There are several ways to determine the effect of a command. The first method is to use the GET
>   DIAGNOSTICS command, which has the form:
>
> GET DIAGNOSTICS variable = item [ , ... ];This command allows
>   retrieval of system status indicators. Each item is a key word
>   identifying a state value to be assigned to the specified variable
>   (which should be of the right data type to receive it). The currently
>   available status items are ROW_COUNT, the number of rows processed by
>   the last SQL command sent down to the SQL engine, and RESULT_OID, the
>   OID of the last row inserted by the most recent SQL command. Note that
>   RESULT_OID is only useful after an INSERT command into a table
>   containing OIDs.
>
> An example:
>
> GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT; The second method to
>   determine the effects of a command is to check the special variable
>   named FOUND, which is of type boolean. FOUND starts out false within
>   each PL/pgSQL function call. It is set by each of the following types
>   of statements:
>
> A SELECT INTO statement sets FOUND true if a row is assigned, false if
>   no row is returned.
>
> A PERFORM statement sets FOUND true if it produces (and discards) a
>   row, false if no row is produced.
>
> UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements set FOUND true if at least one
>   row is affected, false if no row is affected.
>
> A FETCH statement sets FOUND true if it returns a row, false if no row
>   is returned.
>
> A FOR statement sets FOUND true if it iterates one or more times, else
>   false. This applies to all three variants of the FOR statement
>   (integer FOR loops, record-set FOR loops, and dynamic record-set FOR
>   loops). FOUND is set this way when the FOR loop exits; inside the
>   execution of the loop, FOUND is not modified by the FOR statement,
>   although it may be changed by the execution of other statements within
>   the loop body.
>
> FOUND is a local variable within each PL/pgSQL function; any changes
>   to it affect only the current function.

Comment: Yes, ROW_COUNT is what you need.

Comment: Quoting the manual is not at all useful.  Links are fine.  But I come to stackoverflow for examples.

Answer (score 14):

For a very robust solution, that is part of PostgreSQL SQL and not just plpgsql you could also do the following:

```
with a as (DELETE FROM feeds_item WHERE shareurl ~ re1 returning 1)
select count(*) from a;
```

You can actually get lots more information such as:

```
with a as (delete from sales returning amount)
select sum(amount) from a;
```

to see totals, in this way you could get any aggregate and even group and filter it.

Comment: I think that should be `shareurl ~ re1`. Aside from that, great answer! I'll add this to my bag of tricks.

Comment: If this is a sored proceedure what variable type is `a`?

Comment: sadly, this syntax does not work in Greenplum (Postgress 8.2)

Answer (score 4):

I would to share my code (I had this idea from Roelof Rossouw):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.sp_delete_mytable(_id integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    AFFECTEDROWS integer;
  BEGIN
    WITH a AS (DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = _id RETURNING 1)
    SELECT count(*) INTO AFFECTEDROWS FROM a;
    IF AFFECTEDROWS = 1 THEN
      RETURN 1;
    ELSE
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```