# How to check if deletion was successful in PostgreSQL function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `PostgreSQL` function which deletes rows from table.
There can be a situation where a row that I want to delete was already deleted by someone else.. In that case I want to abort the function and roll back everything it's done.

The [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-delete.html) doesn't say how do I know if `DELETE` statement return without doing any deletion.

I wrote this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1()
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
declare 
    line record;
    errorint int;
for line in select * from tab  where ...
LOOP
        DELETE from x WHERE...
        if 0 row deleted then:
            errorint =1;
            raise exception 'delete error';
end loop;               
return 0;           
exception
        when raise_exception then
            return errorint;
end;                
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

The `DELETE` statement will delete **1 or 0 row only**. The `WHERE` gives only one row. meaning that success is when it says `"Query returned successfully: 1 rows affected"` and fail is when it says `"Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected"`. I just don't know how to check what it returns. If there is another way to check it that would be acceptable as well.

Basically my question is how to convert the `if 0 row deleted then` to `PostgreSQL` syntax.

Comment: you can use `raise notice` for verification

Comment: How will that solve my problem? I need to know when the DELETE didn't affect any row. How does `raise notice` help with that?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS

Comment: That should solve my problem... but it raised another question.The first  `GET DIAGNOSTICS ` is irrelevant as   `only useful after an INSERT command `. the second  `GET DIAGNOSTICS ` can only distinguished between 0 rows to many rows. Can't tell HOW MANY. It gives True or False answer. The third, don't give any information. Is there really no way to know how many rows were effected? It doesn't make any seance.. This information is printed into the console when the query is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is a [mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion), and i think you have to look for table/row locking. But if you want a rapid answer that gives you how much rows were deleted, please look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19922381)