# No Implicit variable as an alternative to @@ROWCOUNT/SQL%ROWCOUNT

Tags: postgresql

I am presently migrating from SQL server to Postgresql and this is a huge problem that i am facing.I cant find an Implicit variable as an alternative to `@@ROWCOUNT/SQL%ROWCOUNT` in Postgresql.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109074/rowcount-in-postgresql-9-3 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115917/variable-containing-the-number-of-rows-affected-by-previous-delete-in-a-functi ?

Comment: [`pg_stat_xact_user_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html)